# What is the purpose of @SmallTest, @MediumTest, and @LargeTest annotations in Android?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, tdd, android-espresso

I'm new to Android and I've seen example code using these annotations. For example:

```
@SmallTest
public void testStuff() {
    TouchUtils.tapView(this, anEditTextView);
    sendKeys("H E L P SPACE M E PERIOD");
    assertEquals("help me.", anEditTextView.getText().toString());
}
```

What does that annotation accomplish?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As an addition to [Davidann's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4671991/1083957) and mainly [OP's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671923/what-is-the-purpose-of-smalltest-mediumtest-and-largetest-annotations-in-an#comment5149140_4671991) in the comment:

> In the context of the code above, does it actually **DO** anything except leave a note for other developers? Does it enforce anything? Are there any tools that utilizes this annotation? What's it's purpose in Android development?

You can run a group of tests annotated with specific annotation.

From [AndroidJUnitRunner documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/runner/AndroidJUnitRunner.html):

> Running a specific test size i.e. annotated with **SmallTest** or **MediumTest** or **LargeTest**:
>
> **adb shell am instrument -w -e size [small|medium|large] com.android.foo/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner**

You may also setup those params through gradle:

```
    android {
        ...
        defaultConfig {
            ...
            testInstrumentationRunnerArgument 'size', 'Large'
        }
    }
```

Via gradle:

```
-Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.size=small
```

See [Doug Stevenson blog post](https://medium.com/mesmerhq/accelerate-your-android-espresso-testing-by-grouping-relevant-tests-f492d4ff8809) as well as [this blog post](https://medium.com/@satyajit/running-subset-of-espresso-tests-locally-and-gcloud-4713931da56) for more details.

Comment: OK, so in short I can run only @SmallTest test suite with `adb shell am instrument -w -e size small com.android.foo/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner`; thanks

Comment: How do we specify the annotation in a gradle command? For example, something like: `./gradlew connectedDebugAndroidTest -size MediumTest`

Comment: @Mr-IDE, did you get the answer?

Answer (score 154):

[This blog post](http://googletesting.blogspot.com/2010/12/test-sizes.html) explains it best.  Basically, it is the following:

[image: testing chart]

1. Small: this test doesn't interact with any file system or network.
2. Medium:  Accesses file systems on box which is running tests.
3. Large: Accesses external file systems, networks, etc.

Per the [Android Developers blog](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/TPy1EeSaSg8), a small test should take < 100ms, a medium test < 2s, and a large test < 120s.

[The answer from azizbekian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45637118/52509) shows **how** to utilize the annotation when running your tests.

Also, [this old out-of-date page](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Fq97zvBFAcMJ:https://docs.huihoo.com/android/3.0/guide/developing/testing/testing_otheride.html+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us#AMOptionsSyntax) has even more information.  Specifically, how to use the `am instrument` tool with `adb shell`.  Here's the pertinent parts:

---

### am instrument options

The `am instrument` tool passes testing options to `InstrumentationTestRunner` or a subclass in the form of key-value pairs, using the -e flag, with this syntax:

```sh
-e <key> <value>
```

Some keys accept multiple values. You specify multiple values in a comma-separated list. For example, this invocation of `InstrumentationTestRunner` provides multiple values for the `package` key:

```sh
$ adb shell am instrument -w -e package com.android.test.package1,com.android.test.package2 \
> com.android.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
```

The following table describes the key-value pairs and their result. Please review the Usage Notes following the table.

| Key | Value | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| size | [small | medium | large] | Runs a test method annotated by size. The annotations are @SmallTest, @MediumTest, and @LargeTest. |

---

So reading the above, you could specify small tests like this:

```sh
$ adb shell am instrument -w \
>   -e package com.android.test.package1,com.android.test.package2 \
>   -e size small \
>  com.android.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
```

Comment: I see (and remember reading that article last month).  But in the context of the code above, does it actually DO anything except leave a note for other developers?  Does it enforce anything?  Are there any tools that utilizes this annotation?  What's it's purpose in Android development?

Comment: @Eric The Android TestRunner allows you to specify what size of tests to run.

Comment: Ah, I see.  There's quite a bit of Android docs for me to get through still.  I suppose this is a good thing.  Thanks David and Mayra.

Comment: There is a newer blog from Google on this matter: https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/TPy1EeSaSg8

Comment: @SmallTest is deprecated

Comment: @NeonWarge  use import android.support.test.filters.[Small]Test;

Comment: "See this page (search for "@SmallTest") on how to specify which tests get run." - that's the exact reason why link-only answers are discouraged.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question? Is it a documentation only, a hint for a test runtime, somehow enforced policy?

Comment: Last link is broken

Answer (score 2):

You can also annotate POJO unit tests with `@Category(MediumTest.class)` or `@Category(LargeTest.class)`, etc. by defining your own [Categories](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/categories) - see the [test-categories](https://bitbucket.org/xni06/test-categories) repo for an example