# Robotium testing: empty test suite

Tags: android, automated-tests, robotium

Can't make Robotium work. It used to, but now always fails with an error:
`Running tests
Test running startedFinish
Empty test suite.`

My test draft:

```
public class MainActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 <MainActivity> {

private Solo solo;

public MainActivityTest() {
    super(MainActivity.class);
}

@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
}

@Override
protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
    super.tearDown();
    solo.finishOpenedActivities();
}

@Override
protected void runTest() throws Throwable {
    super.runTest();
}
```

}

build.gradle

```
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "my.app"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<instrumentation
android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
android:targetPackage="my.app"/>
```

In `Edit configurations` for instrumentation runner I have `android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner`. Where's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

which i have figured out for empty test and started test finished test was that my run test was unable to call test method, to do so you have to prefix your **MainActivity** class method to **test MainActivity method**.
e.g

```
Class MAinActivity extends Activity{ //Class A

  public void calculateSomething(){}

}

Class MAinActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 <MainActivity>{ //Class B - Test Class in your case MainActivityTest 

  @TestCalculate
  public void testCalculateSomething(){
        //Do your testing here
  }

}
```

Dont forgot the sequence of calling your main Activity Functions would be same as here in TestClass.

for more info please check
[Why is the Android test runner reporting "Empty test suite"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381694/why-is-the-android-test-runner-reporting-empty-test-suite)