# Class not found: Empty test suite when running unit tests in Android Studio

Tags: android, unit-testing

I have a test suite for my Android app, and all unit tests run fine. However, whenever I make a single change in one of my unit test classes (for example, `ModelUnitTests`), when trying to run that class again, I get this message

```
Process finished with exit code 1
Class not found: "xxx.xxxxxx.xxx.ModelUnitTests"Empty test suite.
```

If I do a gradle clean and then run the class tests again, it runs fine (but it takes 4 minutes to do...), but then a new change will break it again.

Any advice on how to fix this? I'm not exactly sure which test configuration should I post. I'm using the Unit Tests artifact and my tests are located on the
`module/src/test/package` folder

Comment: If you are using Robolectric, check if the test file is in the `$MODULE$/test` directory instead of `$MODULE$/androidTest`

It happened to me, I spent about one hour to figured it out

Comment: Related post - [Why is the Android test runner reporting “Empty test suite”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14381694/465053) & [Class Not Found: Empty Test Suite in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39282282/465053)

Comment: I have a similar problem but it only happens once after opening Android studio. But all I have to do is try to run the test a second time. Then it runs and continues to run until I have to restart Android studio. Something is not right but the annoyance has been little enough that I have ignored it to date.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

I had a similar problem and it was because I first **created an Unit Test with the same class name**. When I created the Instrumented Unit Test I got the error.

To solve it, I went to Edit Configurations, on the left of the run icon. Then below **Unit Test**, it was the **'conflicting'** class, which **I deleted**. Click on Apply/Ok. Then I right click on the class name, click on run and voilà, it works.

Comment: The cause in my case was that I had switched to a release build config at some point which has a different applicationId. Android Studio kept trying to use the release applicationId for the test even though I switched back to the debug config.

Comment: When this happens I just delete all my run configs from AS, as described above, and try again. Likely it's happened because I made some changes to the test class or switched to a branch where there are differences in the test class.

Comment: Thanks ! I spent a lot of time to understand what was happening.I also had an issue between release and debug.

Comment: Tha'nks this was exactly my problem

Answer (score 24):

The fix on Android Studio is:

- step 1.- Go to Run/Debug configuration
- step 2.- Go to Android Tests section
- step 3.- Remove the test configuration file with (-)
- step 4.- Press Apply and OK
- step 5.- Run the test again

Comment: Thank you, this worked, seems like Android Studio bug. I also had to remove my tests from Unit Tests section, it was mistakenly registered there for obscure reasons.

Answer (score 16):

Just ran into this - writing my unit tests in Kotlin. In my case it turned out I forgot to add kotlin plugin in given modules `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
```

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem.  I noticed that the method under test was being displayed in the Run/Debug configuration drop-down as:
`TestClassName.testMethod()`
rather than the correct:
`testMethod()`

I fixed it by deleting the `TestClass.testMethod()` Run/Debug configuration for the test method which was giving this error, then re-running the test.

If that recreates the same problem, delete the incorrect Run/Debug configuration, then right-click on the test method and select:
    `Create 'testMethod()'...`
(rather than Run or Debug) to create a working configuration.

Comment: Crap! Two years later and this hack still helps.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem, and none of the answers on this post (or the other highly-visible Stack Overflow posts) resolved it for me.
However, manually running the gradle task **compileTestKotlin** appears to have resolved the issue for me.

This was for Kotlin tests, Android Studio 3.1.2

Answer (score 3):

If you are working on a team, check all your `build.gradle` files to make sure nobody is disabling the test tasks. I had the 'empty test suite' error and eventually found it was caused by the following in `build.gradle` at the project root:

```
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {
    tasks.each { task ->
        if (task.name.contains("Test"))
        {
            task.enabled = false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use Robolectric you may need to set Working directory in run configuration as $MODULE_DIR$[image]

Also set VM Options
:   -ea
or: -noverify

http://robolectric.org/getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was cause by an exception being thrown in the @BeforeClass method.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me in AS 3.3.

I'm using flavors and this happened in a module which only has `src/main` and `src/test`.  The app module has `src/main` `src/common` and `src/flavor`.  The build type selected in AS was `flavorDebug`.

To fix it I went to "Run Configurations" and in the "Use classpath of module" dropdown the app module was selected.  Select the module that you would like to test and voila!

Answer (score 0):

Work for me:

- Build > Clean Project
- Run test

Answer (score 0):

For me finally worked:

1. ./gradlew check - checked all the errors and tried to fix as many of them.
2. Restarted Android Studio
3. Created a new configuration for Android JUnit, test kind: all in the directory, selected test directory (app/src/test) and app module.
4. Run tests

Answer (score -3):

I had the same issue. I created Suite Class and it resolved the issue

Answer (score -4):

Solved it using a lower gradle version

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
```

That will have to do for now