# IntelliJ : Class not found: "" Empty test suite

Tags: java, testing

I am new to java. I am working on my school project, and I ran into this problem with the error message.

```
Class not found: ""Empty test suite.
```

I have done tests like this before, and they worked.

I did not write all the methods. I tried to run the file first. I have looked for the solutions but none of them work for my situation.

Here is my test code:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class TestLab06 {

@Test
public void testIntListInsert() {
    int[] arr = {1, 3, 5};
    IntList test1 = new IntList(arr);
    IntList test2 = new IntList();
    test1.insert(2, 1);
    test1.insert(4, 3);
    assertEquals(5, test1.getSize());
    assertEquals(3, test1.get(2));
    assertEquals(4, test1.get(3));
    test2.insert(1, 1);
    assertEquals(1, test2.get(0));
    assertEquals(1, test2.getSize());
    test2.insert(10, 10);
    assertEquals(10, test2.get(1));
}

@Test
public void testIntListMerge() {
    int[] arr = {1, 3, 5};
    IntList test1 = new IntList(arr);
    int[] arr2 = {2, 4, 6, 8};
    IntList test2 = new IntList(arr2);
    IntList test = IntList.merge(test1, test2);
    int[] expected ={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8};
    for (int i = 0; i < expected.length; i++) {
        assertEquals(expected[i], test.get(i));
    }
}

@Test
public void testIntListReverse() {
    int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8};
    IntList test1 = new IntList(arr);
    test1.reverse();
    int[] expected = {8, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
    for (int i = 0; i < expected.length; i++) {
        assertEquals(expected[i], test1.get(i));
    }
}

@Test
public void testDLLInsertRemove() {
    DLList l = new DLList();
    l.insertBack(2);
    l.insertFront(1);
    assertEquals(1, l.get(0));
    l.insert(4, 1);
    assertEquals(4, l.get(1));
    l.insert(1, 10);
    // List is 1, 4, 2, 1
    assertEquals(l.sentinel, l.sentinel.next.next.next.next.prev.prev.prev.prev);
    l.remove(1);
    assertEquals(2, l.size);
    l.remove(l.sentinel.next);
    assertEquals(1, l.size);
    assertEquals(2, l.sentinel.next.item);
}

@Test
public void testDLLDoubleReverse() {
    DLList l = new DLList();
    l.insertBack(4);
    l.insertBack(2);
    l.doubleInPlace();
    assertEquals(4, l.size);
    assertEquals(4, l.get(0));
    assertEquals(4, l.get(1));
    assertEquals(2, l.get(2));
    assertEquals(2, l.get(3));
    assertEquals(l.sentinel, l.sentinel.next.next.next.next.prev.prev.prev.prev);
    l.reverse();
    assertEquals(4, l.size);
    assertEquals(4, l.get(3));
    assertEquals(4, l.get(2));
    assertEquals(2, l.get(1));
    assertEquals(2, l.get(0));
    assertEquals(l.sentinel, l.sentinel.next.next.next.next.prev.prev.prev.prev);
}
}
```

and this here is my IntList.java

```
/** A data structure to represent a Linked List of Integers.
 * Each IntList represents one node in the overall Linked List.
 * Encapsulated version.
 */
public class IntList {
    /** The head of the list is the first node in the list. If the list 
is empty, head is null **/
private IntListNode head;
private int size;

/** IntListNode is a nested class. It can be instantiated when associated with an instance of
 *  IntList.
 *  **/
public class IntListNode {
    int item;
    IntListNode next;

    public IntListNode(int item, IntListNode next) {
        this.item = item;
        this.next = next;
    }
}

public int getSize() {
    return size;
}

public IntList() {}

public IntList(int[] initial) {
    for (int i = initial.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        head = new IntListNode(initial[i], head);
    }
    size = initial.length;
}

/**
 * Get the value at position pos. If the position does not exist, throw an
 * IndexOutOfBoundsException.
 * @param position to get from
 * @return the int at the position in the list.
 */
public int get(int position) {
    if (position >= size) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Position larger than size of list.");
    IntListNode curr = head;
    while (position > 0) {
        curr = curr.next;
        position--;
    }
    return curr.item;
}

@java.lang.Override
public java.lang.String toString() {
    return "IntList{" +
            "head=" + head +
            ", size=" + size +
            '}';
}

public boolean equals(Object object) {
    if (this == object) return true;
    if (!(object instanceof IntList)) return false;
    if (!super.equals(object)) return false;
    IntList intList = (IntList) object;
    return size == intList.size &&
            java.util.Objects.equals(head, intList.head);
}



/* Fill in below! */

/**
 * Insert a new node into the IntList.
 * @param x value to insert
 * @param position position to insert into. If position exceeds the size of the list, insert into
 *            the end of the list.
 */
public void insert(int x, int position) {
    // Fill me in!
    //insert when the size of the list is 0
    if (this.size == 0) {
        head = new InListNode(x, head);
        size++;

    }
    //insert at the beginning of the list
    else if (position == 0) {
        IntListNode new_node = new IntListNode(x, head);
        head = new_node;
        size++;
    }
    else {
        IntListNode point = head;
        while (position > 1 && point.next != null) {
            point = point.next;
            position--;
        }
        IntListNode newone = new IntListNode(x, point.next);
        point.next = newone;
        size++;
    }


}

/**
 * Merge two sorted IntLists a and b into one sorted IntList containing all of their elements.
 * @return a new IntList without modifying either parameter
 */
public static IntList merge(IntList a, IntList b) {
    // Fill me in!
    return null;
}

/**
 * Reverse the current list recursively, using a helper method.
 */
public void reverse() {
    // Fill me in!
}

/* Optional! */

/**
 * Remove the node at position from this list.
 * @param position int representing the index of the node to remove. If greater than the size
 *                 of this list, throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException.
 */
public void remove(int position) {
    if (position >= size) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    // fill me in
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Class Not Found: Empty Test Suite in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39282282/class-not-found-empty-test-suite-in-intellij)

Comment: I understand your intention of only posting what you think is the important part of the error/traceback, but it's much more helpful if you copy and paste the whole thing into your post, @xing.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

**File** > **Invalidate Caches/Restart** > **Invalidate and Restart**

Answer (score 1):

Try to run tests from console: [How to run JUnit test cases from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235276/how-to-run-junit-test-cases-from-the-command-line)

If it works, delete `idea/` folder and `*.iml` file if exists. Be sure you are using latest version of IDE and re-import it.

Answer (score 0):

My problem were the dependencies.
Go to your pom.xml file and add below `</build>`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Maven is uncommon for Android - should use Gradle examples instead