# Type Android Junit4 not present exception

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, junit4

I have an Android project that I am trying to run Instrumentation tests for using AndroidStudio, but when I try to run the whole class file for the tests, I get the exceptions as stated below :

```
java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4 not present
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4
```

Interestingly, I can run individual methods in this Instrument Test class, just not the whole class. My build.gradle file for the app is below:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sarpuner.journal"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
}

repositories {
    maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/ijabz/maven" }
}

dependencies {
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.1.1'
    implementation 'net.jthink:jaudiotagger:2.2.3'
    api 'com.google.guava:guava:26.0-android'
}
```

And the InstrumentTest class is as follows:

```
package com.sarpuner.journal

import android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4
import android.util.Log    
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith    
import org.junit.Assert.*
import java.io.File

private const val INSTRUMENT_TAG = "InstrumentTest"

// TODO: There is a problem here with the class run!

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class ExampleInstrumentedTest {

    private val appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()

    @Test
    fun useAppContext() {
        // Context of the app under test.
        assertEquals("com.sarpuner.journal", appContext.packageName)
    }

    @Test
    fun downloadAndSaveAudio() {
        val url = "http://telechargement.rfi.fr/rfi/francais/audio/jff/201808/journal_francais_facile_20h00_-_20h10_tu_20180809.mp3"
        val name = "09-08-2018.mp3"
        val f = File(appContext.filesDir, name)
        Log.d(INSTRUMENT_TAG, f.absolutePath)
        downloadAudio(url, f)
    }

    @Test
    fun downloadAndSaveTranscript() {
        val url = "https://savoirs.rfi.fr/fr/apprendre-enseigner/langue-francaise/journal-en-francais-facile-09082018-20h00-gmt"
        val name = "09-08-2018.txt"
        val f = File(appContext.filesDir, name)

        downloadText(url, f)
    }

    @Test
    fun addLyricsToAudio() {

    }
}
```

Any help/guidance is much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

This is caused by Android Studio trying to execute an instrumentation test as a JUnit test.

I had to go to 'Edit Configurations...' and delete the configuration from Android JUnit group and manually add to the 'Android Instrumented Tests' group. After this I had no problem executing the tests.

In Android Studio, click `Run > Edit Configurations`.

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/rundebugconfig

Comment: This is correct and should be accepted as a correct answer.

Comment: @Bohsen How to do that, any steps ?

Comment: Why does Android Studio continue to try to add it to the JUnit tests instead of instrumented tests though? I don't want to have to manually adjust configuration for every test.

Comment: @FutureShocked in my case the reason was that the device was not recognized properly. I had some general usb recognition issue with my device. Additionally some phones ask for permission to allow access from the PC

Comment: I continue to face this issue, and pretty strictly use an emulator for instrumented testing.

Comment: @FutureShocked I've never checked if this issue was raised on Googles issue Tracker. Might be worth rasing.

Answer (score 10):

**Writing steps if someone facing issue while edit configuration for above @Bohsen's answe**r

1. In Android Studio, click `Run > Edit Configurations` (or press `alt + shift + f10` if on Windows) to open the configuration editor.
2. The left panel of the window shows configurations and their groups.

   - Android JUnit group
   - Android instrumented tests

If your test is an instrumentation test, delete it from any JUnit tests groups.

If your test is a JUnit test, delete it from any instrumentation test groups.

For example, my test (DBTest.kt) was appearing in both **Android JUnit and Instrumented group's section**. So I deleted from JUnit group and ran it again, it was working fine.

Answer (score 4):

Hopefully someone can give you a better answer as to why, but I had this exact same problem. I did the following:

- Build > Clean Project,
- Ran the app on the emulator

This done, I was able to get back into a state where I could run the tests again.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39282282/class-not-found-empty-test-suite-in-intellij Also appears to help

Comment: Android Studio unit tests are flaky as hell. I've had to clear caches and clean builds at almost every step. Makes TDD very tedious.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same with:

```
Type androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4 not present
```

I tried a lot of things before manually removing the App from the device and running the test again. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For me this actually seemed to be caused by an internet connection issue.  Turning off and on wifi fixed and rebuilding seemed to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue when I did my tests on the emulator.

I fixed it by downloading a new project copy from the git repository.