# Junit5 and Instrumentation Tests running when running unit tests

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, instrumentation, junit5

I upgraded my tests to junit5 now when I run my unit tests it also runs my instrumentation test which of course causes errors as they're not running in a simulator.  How do I stop it from running them?  I was able to solve some of the errors using @RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class) but I still have one error and it’s driving me crazy

this is the error, however, I do not understand why my instrumentation tests are now running when I click on Run???

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: androidx/test/espresso/matcher/ViewMatchers

    at com.magtec.magtecmcc.MainActivityTest.testLaunch(MainActivityTest.kt:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:531)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$2.lambda$evaluate$0(SandboxTestRunner.java:256)
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.Sandbox.lambda$runOnMainThread$0(Sandbox.java:89)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.SandboxClassLoader.getByteCode(SandboxClassLoader.java:164)
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.SandboxClassLoader.maybeInstrumentClass(SandboxClassLoader.java:119)
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.SandboxClassLoader.lambda$findClass$0(SandboxClassLoader.java:112)
    at org.robolectric.util.PerfStatsCollector.measure(PerfStatsCollector.java:53)
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.SandboxClassLoader.findClass(SandboxClassLoader.java:111)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 19 more
```

Comment: You should be able to stop tests from being run with @Ignore annotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

multiple options first individually for tests:

- @Ignore if you want to completely disable
- put assumeTrue(condition); to deactivate a test on runtime conditions
- and then you can also do this:
  start the test first
  then click on the dropdown menu at the top that displays your run configuration
  click on Edit Configurations

  - change the folder of the configuration to one that excludes your specific tests
  - or switch test kind to pattern and hope you have some kind of naming convention for the excluding testfiles then you can write a regex pattern that only includes the ones you want

Comment: Great answer :)

as for the last one I already have it set to the test folder only (yet it's still running the android test folder???)

as you can see here
https://imgur.com/a/lbolJ6N

Comment: Id recommend going with the pattern filter then and excluding every Test that contains "Instrumented" also maybe it helps setting some random weird sesttings to see if changes take effect

Comment: So I noticed that if I did clear cache (then it would run only the folder, finally)
I found this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51832349/type-android-junit4-not-present-exception
Seemed to work.