# Class not found. Test class not found

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso

Here is it my sreen:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/L98fHex]

What settings should I set?
How to avoid deprecated class?

I would like to use espresso, after that try to use UiAutomator, how to set needed necessary settings?

I lost almost whole day.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@LargeTest
```

```
class MainActivityTest {

    @Rule
    @JvmField
    var activityTest = ActivityTestRule(MainActivity::class.java)

    fun c(){
        assertEquals(1,1)
    }
}
```

GRADLE

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.network"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.2.0'

    //okhttp library
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.7.2")
    // coroutines
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.7'
    //gson
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    //recycler
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0"
    //picasso
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    //broadcast
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    //interceptor
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.7.0'
}
```

Comment: Please add sourcecode as formatted text and not as an image.

Comment: @TomStroemer , all done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not set the [test runner](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-runner) correctly.

This line:

```
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

should be instead:

```
testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

as you are using the new `androidx` libraries instead of the old `support` ones.

Without this you'll get this `No tests were found` errors. Don't forget to add the `testInstrumentationRunner` keyword.

And add junit to androidTestImplementation also in de gradle file:

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
```

Comment: I set "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner",
And it throws java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4 not present. 
Also in test class @RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class) glows as deprecated

Comment: Add junit4 to `androidTestImplementation` also in the gradle file and not only in `testImplementation`. Then, once it works, check this for the deprecation error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52776716/androidjunit4-class-is-deprecated-how-to-use-androidx-test-ext-junit-runners-an/52776938

Comment: thank you for responding!
I set androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'

Comment: I tried to start test, but it shows java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4 not present 
this is little strange :(

Comment: I set androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
It doesn't glows as deprecated.
But shows java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4 not present. In this reference that You sent to me, there is something like: Change test class to AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner from AndroidJUnit4

Comment: Maybe you have the old import of junit4 in the test files. With this last one it should be: `import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4`. If this doesn't work add the imports of the test file to your question and I'll have a look at it all

Comment: that was right. but still java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4 not present

Comment: Check this also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51832349/type-android-junit4-not-present-exception (second most voted answer has the details)

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/uMGUNmg
When I delete it, and just reopen Run -> EditConfig that show again.
Probably something went wrong with my crooked hands...

Comment: Delete them all and run it again by clicking on the play on the test file. This MainActivityTest.e and MainActivityTeste should not appear again

Comment: no, it appears again.
thank you for help, I don't want to lost your time!

Comment: It's really strange. You could search for `MainActivityTeste` in your files (`Find in Path` option of android studio), maybe this might give you a clue of something which is wrong