# Tests in IntelliJ not running

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, intellij-idea, junit

When trying to run tests i get the following error

```
Process finished with exit code 1
Class not found: "com.my.app.api.SomeTest"Empty test suite.
```

I know the test classes are valid and running on a friends machine, but I can't seem to run them on mine.

Comment: Are the tests located under a "Test Source" path?

Comment: yes they are in the test source path

Comment: Show SomeTest class

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39282282/class-not-found-empty-test-suite-in-intellij]) (Duplicate)

Comment: I cannot share SomeTest class but you can imagine its basic junit mockito test class.

Comment: In the project pane, is the test source path coloured **green** ? If not, right click and mark it

Comment: It is colored green

Comment: I just want to say what fixed it: Deleted the repo, downloaded again, build succesfully, tests ran perfectly.