# Android Unit test are giving wrong result

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, android-testing, gradle-android-test-plugi

When I run a unit test for a new created project then it shows me the wrong result **(Says All Tests are passed)**.

If you see in the image below **4 is expected while 6+2 surely not 4**.

[image]

Now when I run the same test from **Gradle** right menu. It shows me the correct result that test has failed.

[image]

Did I do anything wrong or is this an android studio bug?

---

### Edit

Run configuration image

[image]

Comment: check the run configurations, i think the test is not actually running

Comment: @TobiAdeyinka can specify which configuration ?

Comment: how are you running the test?

Comment: In the first scenario, I m clicking the little play  icon left to test name.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem, just check the top right of the IDE next to the run button, there should be a drop down that contains 'edit configurations'

Comment: it should be 'JUnit' instead of 'Android JUnit' under 'Run configuration', what version of AndroidStudio you are using, I don't see an option to create 'Android JUnit'

Comment: @WenChao yes there is not Junit option I am using `Android studio 2.3 beta1`

Comment: I think in the first case it isn't even running the test! Try doing `Log.e()` and see if you can find it in Logcat.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add **-ea** option in the "VM options" box in your 3rd image. This is to enable assertion feature for the JVM. Without this **-ea**, JVM just ignore assertion statement.
When you run the test with gradle, it used a default configuration so that's why your test was run correctly.

Comment: on the first image, in the test result navigator, just right above "All test passed" if you click on the OK green button, it shows which tests did run? Ignore the -ea, it does not matter in your case :)

Comment: first time running test after opening Android studio says no test found

Comment: If there is no ExampleTestClass.class file was generated under build/xxx/classes folder (do a search for all file in the build folder). If it is the case, your "test" folder somehow was not recognised as a "source" folder. Take a look at the app.iml file in your project (<sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/test/java" isTestSource="true" /> ). If you are lucky then delete the file and open/import the project again will work. Or you can find someway to include "test" folder as a source folder.

Comment: not working its preserving the result of previous run Gradle task.

Comment: delete the class file, or change some code or do a clean build to force it to build again. Dont run gradle test, now do you see the class file generated?

Comment: Now it's saying `Class not found: "com.xxx.xxx.network.UrlConstantTest"Empty test suite.`

Comment: found this similar to your issue, hope it help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38056901/class-not-found-empty-test-suite-when-running-unit-tests-in-android-studio