# How can I run both '@SmallTest' and '@MediumTest' and not '@LargeTest'?

Tags: android, adb, android-espresso, android-instrumentation

**Details:**

I want to be able to run all `@SmallTest` and `@MediumTest` tests while ignoring `@LargeTest` tests.

It looks like Android ADB instrumentation commands support negation. For example, you can negate `annotation` like `notAnnotation` but I do not see a `notSize` for `size`.

Ideally it would be nice to have something similar to: `adb shell am instrument -w -e notSize large com.android.foo/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner`.

I rather not create custom annotations and then be forced to re-annotate all of my tests.

**I have tried the following:**

- Tried `notSize`:

  - `adb shell am instrument -w -e notSize large com.android.foo/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner`
- 2 `size` parameters:

  - `adb shell am instrument -w -e size small -e size medium com.android.foo.MyAnnotation com.android.foo/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner`

**References**

- [What is the purpose of @SmallTest, @MediumTest, and @LargeTest annotations in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671923/what-is-the-purpose-of-smalltest-mediumtest-and-largetest-annotations-in-an)
- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/InstrumentationTestRunner.html
- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/runner/AndroidJUnitRunner.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `notAnnotation` and specifying the fully qualified path of `LargeTest`:

```
adb shell am instrument -w -e notAnnotation android.support.test.filters.LargeTest com.android.foo/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```

Comment: So is there not a way to pass to parameters and run Small and Medium, except for running "not" Large?